# jquery set to function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, onmouseover

I have a mouseover that looks like the below

```
onmouseover='$(this).css(\"cursor\",\"pointer\");infoCardIn("uid")'
```

I'd like to change it in a jquery function to look like this

```
onmouseover='$(this).css(\"cursor\",\"pointer\");infoCardIn("uid2")'
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right. Help?

Comment: that its REALLY wrong. see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp
in general, you'll want to avoid puting js code inline with the html

Comment: @Jarry If you want to discourage inline js, w3schools is probably not the right place to link to.  Their vanilla js tutorials are riddled with it.

Comment: I'm aware of inline JS being seen as incorrect. However, in some instances it's just easier than using an external method to do one thing that a jquery method already does. I find that a mixture seems more correct than not in certain cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myItem").hover(function() { // Mouse in method
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    infoCardIn("uid2");
}, function() { // Mouse out method
    $(this).css("cursor","");
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for details.

Hope this helps!